# AngularJS compiling PHP-generated code in Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, datatables

I'm having Datatables function serverSide by making ajax requests to a Laravel route.

The laravel route returns data like what is explained on this page: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side, including a column with some HTML.

The columns it populates includes an Actions column where I want to have links that use angular directives like ngClick and ngClass. I know that the HTML in the columns needs to be compiled in order for them to work, but I don't know how to go about doing it, especially since it is being generated by PHP.

Comment: I would put the table in a directive and use jquery events to make scope adjustments using `$apply`

Answer (score 0):

Used a callback http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow to call $compile on the whole row so each row is processed by the compiler.

```
elem.DataTable({
  ...
  createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $compile(row)($scope)
  ...
});
```